# How to unfold the navigate panel at the start of the shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

This is how my app looks like now at the start:
[image]

The problem is that some users don't know that above list can be unfolded by clicking on it. Is it possible to set it as unfolded at the start of app?

this is how i want it looks like at the start:
[image]

Comment: can you please explain what do u mean by unfold? Can you share a screenshot on what is your expected result?

Comment: I put 2 images: first how it is now and second how i want it

Comment: This could be done on the client side, using Javascript. But that's kind of an odd thing to do with a nav bar.. Would you consider a different UI control? Perhaps tabs in the main panel, or radio buttons in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you might programmatically manipulate a navbar using Javascript.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML("
      Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('click-navbar-menu', function(message) {
        var menuName = message.menuName;
        $('.nav').find('a[data-value=\"' + menuName + '\"]').click();
      })"))
  ),

  navbarPage("App Title",
             tabPanel("Plot"),
             navbarMenu("More",
                        menuName = "more",
                        tabPanel("Summary"),
                        "----",
                        "Section header",
                        tabPanel("Table")
             )
  )
)

clickNavbarMenu <- function(menuName, session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()) {
  session$sendCustomMessage("click-navbar-menu", list(menuName = menuName))
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  clickNavbarMenu("more")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you don't need to control it from the server (one-time only deal when you load the app), you could strip it down and just run a simple script with hard-coded values like:

```
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML("
      $(function() {
        $('.nav').find('a[data-value=\"more\"]').click();
      });"))
  )
```